# Finding optimal substructure

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm looking for some pointers about a dynamic programming problem. I cannot find any relevant information about how to solve this kind of problem.

Problem

```
 A number is called a special number if it doesn't contain 3 consecutive 
 zeroes. i have to calculate the number of positive integers of exactly d digits 
 that are special answer should be modulo 1000000007(just for overflow in c++).
```

Problem can easily solved by permutation and combination but i want it with dynamic programming. 
I am unable to find its optimal substructure or bottom to top approach.

Comment: even after you find out the recurrence, i doubt you would want to use DP here as there aren't any overlapping sub-structures.
edit: i might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let `f(d,x)` be the amount of most significant `d` digits whose last `x` digits are zeros, where 0 ≤ `x` ≤ 2. For `d` > 1, We have the recurrence:

```
f(d,0) = (f(d-1,0) + f(d-1,1) + f(d-1,2)) * 9  // f(d,0) comes from any d-1 digits patterns appended a non-zero digit 
f(d,1) = f(d-1,0) // f(d,1) comes from the d-1 digits patterns without tailing zeros appended by a zero
f(d,2) = f(d-1,1) // f(d,2) comes from the d-1 digits patterns with one tailing zero appended by a zero
```

And for `d` = 1, we have `f(1,0) = 9, f(1,1) = 0, f(1,2) = 0`.

The final answer for the original problem is `f(d,0) + f(d,1) + f(d,2)`.

Here is a simple C program for demo:

```
#include <cstdio>

const int MOD = 1000000007;
long long f[128][3];

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  f[1][0] = 9;
  for (int i = 2 ; i <= n ; ++i) {
    f[i][0] = (f[i-1][0] + f[i-1][1] + f[i-1][2]) * 9 % MOD;
    f[i][1] = f[i-1][0];
    f[i][2] = f[i-1][1];
  }
  printf("%lld\n", (f[n][0] + f[n][1] + f[n][2]) % MOD);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that this method can also be considered as combinatorial to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: i haven't tested out my logic thoroughly, so please point out where i might be wrong.

The recurrence for the problem can be

`f(d)=f(d/2)*f(d-d/2)-( f(d/2-1)*f(d-d/2-2) + f(d/2-2)*f(d-d/2-1) )`
`f(0)=1;f(1)=10;f(2)=100;f(3)=999;`

here, `f(i)` is the total number special digits that can be formed considering that '0' can occur as the first digit. So, the actual answer for a 'd' digit number would be `9*f(d-1)`.

You can easily memoize the recurrence solution to make a DP solution.

I haven't tried out the validity of this solution, so it might be wrong. 
Here is my logic:

for `f(d)`, divide/partition the number into `d/2` and `(d-d/2)` digit numbers, add the product of `f(d)*f(d-d/2)`. Now, to remove the invalid cases which may occur across the partition we made, subtract `f(d/2-1)*f(d-d/2-2) + f(d/2-2)*f(d-d/2-1)` from the answer (assume that three zero occur across the partition we made). Try it with paper and pen and you will get it.

Comment: I think there is a mistake that an invalid case may be removed twice. For example, 4 zeros occur across the partition and both sides contain 2 of them.